# cloud9 crypto is not working at all been trying for days

Tags: node.js, undefined, cryptoapi, cloud9-ide

I am trying to get a setup work with utils, the problem is it can not find the crypto module.

I have install utils and crypto using npm install then when I run my script

```
node server.js casper.js
```

I get this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'crypto'

phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
/var/lib/stickshift/53452520e0b8cd1d870002e1/app-root/data/828422/node_modules/utils/utils.js:7
/var/lib/stickshift/53452520e0b8cd1d870002e1/app-root/data/828422/node_modules/utils/utils.js:117
/var/lib/stickshift/53452520e0b8cd1d870002e1/app-root/data/828422/node_modules/utils/utils.js:118
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'utils.inherits(Nightmare, Casper)')

/var/lib/stickshift/53452520e0b8cd1d870002e1/app-root/data/828422/node_modules/nightmarejs/lib/nightmareClient.js:21
/var/lib/stickshift/53452520e0b8cd1d870002e1/app-root/data/828422/node_modules/nightmarejs/lib/nightmareTest.js:16
```

why can it not find crypto. I have tried all different ways to get this working, but no luck 
does any one have any ideas?

package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "chat-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A chat example to showcase how to use `socket.io` with a static `express` server",
  "main": "server.js",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "Mostafa Eweda <mostafa@c9.io>",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "~0.2.8",
    "express": "~3.2.4",
    "socket.io": "~0.9.14",
    "phantomjs": "*",
    "casperjs": "*",
    "nightmarejs": "*",
    "utils": "*",
    "casper": "*"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
var nightmareJS = require('./node_modules/nightmarejs/lib/nightmare').nightmare('test');

nightmareJS.notifyCasperMessage = function(msg) {
    if(msg.type == 'statement') {
        console.log(msg.msg);
        console.log("Nightmare Server says hello.");
    }
    else if(msg.type == 'dateQuestion') {
        console.log(msg.msg);
        var d = new Date();
        nightmareJS.sendCasperMessage({ time: d.toString(), timeNow: d.getTime()});
    }
}
```

casper.js

```
casper.start('http://www.google.com', function() {
    this.test.assertTitle('Google', 'Google has the correct title');
    this.sendMessageToParent({ type: 'statement', msg: 'Hello Nightmare.'})
})

casper.then(function() {
    this.waitForMessageResponse({ type: 'dateQuestion', msg: 'What time is it?'}, 'time', function() {
        var d = new Date();
        this.echo('Nightmare thinks the time is: ' + this.lastDataReceived.time);
        this.log('Nightmare thinks the time is: ' + this.lastDataReceived.time, 'debug');
        this.test.assert(Math.abs(this.lastDataReceived.timeNow - d.getTime()) < 1000, "Nightmare and Casper's times are within 1000 seconds of each other");
    })
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.test.done();
});
```

and then i run the files using

node server.js casper.js

i am trying to get nightmarejs to work but utils cannot find crypto

please someone help i so need this to work

Comment: in the package.json: nightmarejs isn't that supposed to be nightmare ?

Comment: or do you actually want nightmarejs ?

Comment: no i actually want nightmarejs there are no problems with that

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/nightmarejs this has nothing to do with the error i am getting utils cannot find crypto thats the problem

Comment: I have this same problem with node-couchdb on cloud 9. Is this really cloud 9 specific? Have you been  able to get it to work elsewhere?